# How to assign a view object to an XUL tree widget without enablePrivilege

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

I see that `enablePrivilege` is deprecated in Firefox. I am trying to adapt my intranet code base to this.

The most critical place is assigning the 'view' of a 'tree' element.  This requires elevated privs, though I really don't understand why.  Is there another way to do this that does not require the elevated privileges?  Will a way to do this be provided before `enablePrivilege` goes away?

The application is not an extension but a signed JAR file that runs as content.

Comment: The custom tree views were a source of security vulnerabilities which is why setting `tree.view` requires extended privileges starting with Gecko 1.8 I think. Later the same thing happened to all of remote XUL. Generally, I don't think that Mozilla wants to continue supporting web applications with elevated privileges, it is a constant source of trouble. Given that you already have to change a preference to use remote XUL, you can probably install an extension to support your web application just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through [bug 546848](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546848), Mozilla doesn't plan to allow websites with elevated privileges any more. This functionality introduces security risks that are simply not worth it (similarly to remote XUL in general). The proposed solution would be using a Firefox extension to do any special actions that might be needed. Ideally, you would move your entire web application UI into an extension and only leave the server as a backend. But I guess that this solution would require too much effort on your side. A simpler solution would be a single-purpose extension that receives a message from your website and sets the tree view.

[Interaction between privileged and non-privileged pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages) describes how this communication could be implemented. Your website would set a property `_myTreeView` on the `<tree>` element and dispatch an event on it. The extension would receive the event, verify that `event.target.ownerDocument.defaultView.location.host` is your intranet website (important, allowing any website to trigger your extension would be a security hole) and then set `event.target.view = event.target.wrappedJSObject._myTreeView`. See [XPCNativeWrapper documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper) on why `wrappedJSObject` is necessary here.

Comment: I have been trying to get something to work for a while now.  The documents referenced above seem to say that browser code is not allowed to access content data and then the object wrapping mechanism is just meant to enforce that.  Is there someplace with a working example of code that assigns a tree view in an extension on behalf of the content.  This seems to be the only place where there needs to be close interaction between browser and content code and the suggestions I have seen do not seem to work.

Comment: @nicktook: That's why you would use `wrappedJSObject` property, to get direct access to content data...